# Exception.ToString() line numbers are missing

Tags: uwp

In my UWP app, when running a Debug build, calling `ToString()` on an Exception object contains the message and the method name, **but no filename and no line number**. Furthermore, calling `Environment.StackTrace` results in the same missing info for each line.
As per MSDN, `Environment.StackTrace` should output lines with the following format

> at FullClassName.MethodName(MethodParams) in FileName :line LineNumber

... except in the case where debug symbols are not available.

However, I have verified that when debugging (F5) the symbols for my user code are loaded. Also, when paused on a breakpoint after catching an exception, the *Call Stack* window shows line numbers... so the information is there. It's just not included somehow in `Exception.ToString()` or `Environment.StackTrace`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. You can see line number information in debug, but you can't get it. I checked the issue library, someone has already filed this issue before, we will look into this.

<strike>If you want to analyze the error logs, you can try [App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/uwp).</strike>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I got App Center all setup, and tested out a crash. Same result: when viewing the crash report in the online portal, method names are there, but no file or line numbers.

Comment: This is a known issue about not being able to get file and line number information in Visual Stduio, someone has already submitted this problem on [VisualStudio Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Debugger-shows-different-ExceptionStack/10356890). App Center also cannot get the file and line number information, you can see it in GitHub issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/appcenter-docs/issues/462.